# Django grouping results by filed

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, iteration

Sorry for noob question.
Assuming we have a model with relation:

```
  class Book(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
     category = models.ForeignKey(Category)

  class Category(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

Is it possible to somehow group results so in the template we can have something like this?

```
<ul>
   {% for category in book_categories%}
              <li> 
                  {{category.name}} 
                   <br/>  
                  {% for book in category%}
                      {{book.name}} , {{book.author}}, etc...
                  {% endfor %} 
             </li>
   {% endfor %}           
</ul>
```

or am I making things complicated and there is an easier way to achieve html output like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the categories to your template, and then you can do something like this

```
<ul>
   {% for category in categories %}
              <li> 
                  {{category.name}} 
                   <br/>  
                  {% for book in category.book_set.all %}
                      {{book.name}} , {{book.author}}, etc...
                  {% endfor %} 
             </li>
   {% endfor %}           
</ul>
```

Comment: This is it! I knew there were something simple as this) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can load just books sorted by category and then have in template something like this:

```
<ul>
  {% for book in books %}
    <li>
        {% ifchanged book.category__name %}
            {{ book.category__name }}
        {% endifchanged %}

        <br/>  
        {{book.name}} , {{book.author}}, etc...
    </li>
  {% endfor %}          
</ul>
```